# How to create dynamic charts in a power point by using Aspose slides

Tags: aspose-slides

Need help for creating dynamic charts in a power point by using Aspose slides.

Answer (score 1):

@Mohini,

I have observed your requirements and like to share that Aspose.Slides offers you to create MSO charts programmatically. I suggest you to please try using following sample code to create a Clustered Column chart.

```
        // Instantiate Presentation class that represents PPTX file
        Presentation pres = new Presentation();

        // Access first slide
        ISlide sld = pres.Slides[0];

        // Add chart with default data
        IChart chart = sld.Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.ClusteredColumn, 0, 0, 500, 500);

        // Setting chart Title
        // Chart.ChartTitle.TextFrameForOverriding.Text = "Sample Title";
        chart.ChartTitle.AddTextFrameForOverriding("Sample Title");
        chart.ChartTitle.TextFrameForOverriding.TextFrameFormat.CenterText = NullableBool.True;
        chart.ChartTitle.Height = 20;
        chart.HasTitle = true;

        // Set first series to Show Values
        chart.ChartData.Series[0].Labels.DefaultDataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;

        // Setting the index of chart data sheet
        int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;

        // Getting the chart data worksheet
        IChartDataWorkbook fact = chart.ChartData.ChartDataWorkbook;

        // Delete default generated series and categories
        chart.ChartData.Series.Clear();
        chart.ChartData.Categories.Clear();
        int s = chart.ChartData.Series.Count;
        s = chart.ChartData.Categories.Count;

        // Adding new series
        chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "Series 1"), chart.Type);
        chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 2, "Series 2"), chart.Type);

        // Adding new categories
        chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 0, "Caetegoty 1"));
        chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 0, "Caetegoty 2"));
        chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 0, "Caetegoty 3"));

        // Take first chart series
        IChartSeries series = chart.ChartData.Series[0];

        // Now populating series data

        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 20));
        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 50));
        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 30));

        // Setting fill color for series
        series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid;
        series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;


        // Take second chart series
        series = chart.ChartData.Series[1];

        // Now populating series data
        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 2, 30));
        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 10));
        series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 2, 60));

        // Setting fill color for series
        series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid;
        series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Green;

        // First label will be show Category name
        IDataLabel lbl = series.DataPoints[0].Label;
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowCategoryName = true;

        lbl = series.DataPoints[1].Label;
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowSeriesName = true;

        // Show value for third label
        lbl = series.DataPoints[2].Label;
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = true;
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowSeriesName = true;
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.Separator = "/";

        // Save presentation with chart
        pres.Save(dataDir + "AsposeChart_out.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,